# How to edit the styles of extension in Magento?

Tags: css, magento

I have just installed an extension for displaying vertical navigation menu in list page in magento. The Extension is https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/vertical-navigation-with-css-classes.html. It has the left.phtml file in template\vertnav\left.phtml. I want the vertical navigation to be displayed in the template\catalog\layer\view.phtml and change its styles. So I copied the content of left.phtml to view.phtml but error is getting displayed like:

[image]

This is my first extension .Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You can not call each and every method in every file.
Look for  extension xml file.
open it then under catalog_category_default and catalog_category_layered use all the block and css from extension xml tag.
now you can call those functions inside view.phtml